# Not loading the correct value from memory onto a register in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, x86-16

I am very new to 8086 assembly to please excuse the sloppy code and possibly unnecessary lines, I'm self taught. This code is a fragment of another program I'm making, which requires user input in numbers. These specific lines take the input, then produces a number the computer can actually work with. For example, taking 5, 4, and 3 and "compiling" the numbers into 543.

The problem comes up in line 59, where I try to load back a number from memory to register bx, in which case, instead of loading the correct number, like 40 (from the 543 ex.) it just loads a 1.

Some code after line 59 might not even work, because I got stuck there.

I'm probably not using the correct registers, but again, I'm self taught and its hard finding easy to understand information about the syntax online.

```
org  100h

mov si, 100d

input1:
    mov ah, 1h      ;input char
    int 21h
    push ax
    sub al, 30h     ;convert ascii to integer
    mov dl, al      ;put char into dl to be read
    mov [si], al    ;save char to ram for later
    mov ah, 2h      ;output char
    inc si          ;to save on next location in mem 
    pop ax
    cmp al, 13      ;check if done
    jne input1

    dec si              ;insert terination char 
    dec si              ;decrement to save value of si for multilying by ten
    push si             ;save current si value
    inc si              ;then continue
    mov al, 24h
    mov [si], al

    pop si
    mov cx, 1

    compileNum1:
        mov ax, 0
        mov bx, 0
        mov dx, 0    
    .fixNum:
        mov al, [si]   ; load last num into ax to be multiplied by 10
        mul cx
        mov bp, ax
        mov [si], bp
        dec si
        mov al, 10
        mov bx, cx
        mul bl
        mov cx, ax           
        cmp si, 99d
        jne .fixNum

    mov si, 100d       ;starts number addition

    mov ax, [si]       ;loads first number
    inc si             ;prepares second
    mov bx, [si]       ;loads second

    cmp bx, 24h        ;checks if there was only 1 number
    je .terminate1     ;if there was, goto terminate

    add ax, bx         ;else add them together

    .stloop1:
        inc si         ;prepares for third, fourth etc
        mov bx, [si]   ;loads it

        cmp bx, 24h    ;checks if numbver is 3 digts ot more long (depends on loop)
        je .terminate1 ;terminate if so

        add ax, bx     ;add them together, store in ax

    .terminate1:
        mov [100d], ax





mov ax, 0   ;clear screen
int 10h 


mov ah, 2h  ;print char
int 21h

mov ah, 0   
int 16h
ret
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm I usually use to "get a number from the keyboard" - which is actually "get text from the keyboard and convert it to a number" as you realize, goes like this:

preloop:

set a "result so far" register to zero.

set a 16-bit register to 10 to use as a multiplier

loop:

Get a text character. You can get 'em one at a time, as you're doing, or load one at a time from an input buffer where the user has put it.

Assure that you've got a decimal digit - those pesky users will type any darn thing! You may want to accept '+' and/or '-'. I'd watch for 13 (CR) or other terminating character here, rather than at the end as you're doing (you don't really want to apply the "convert to number" algorithm to CR). You can do what you want about "garbage input", if any.

Simplest thing is to assume a well-behaved user. I usually just return the number I've got so far - even if zero. A polite error message and let 'em retry would be best.

Once you've got a valid decimal digit, subtract `'0'` from the character - note that this is the character '0', not the number 0.. You can call it 48 or 30h if you like, but I think '0' is more obvious "what it's for".

Then multiply the "result so far" by 10.

Then add the number obtained from the current digit. This can be a little trickey. We can't `add ax, bl`. We can `add ax, bx`, but we have to be sure `bh` is zero! (change registers to suit your purposes)

Repeat until we find that CR (or other terminating character). That's it, the number is in "result so far".

Hope this helps. You're on the right track, but making it more complicated than it needs to be, I think. Kudos for figuring it out on your own so far!

When it comes to the "number to text" part, I saw a really sweet, simple example posted by one of the regulars here just the other day. My memory's bad. 
You can probably find it if you need it.